# How can I set a minimum range for an interval for a time scale in d3.js?

Tags: coffeescript, d3.js, data-visualization

My question is probably poorly phrased, you're welcome to edit it.

My problem is simple. I'm making a timeline in plain HTML using d3. Timelines items (articles here) all have a fixed height (let's say 100px), but I need them not to overlap like this:

[image: Overlapping articles (bad)]

There are 4 articles here and as you can see, it's unreadable. I know what the problem is but I have no idea how to solve it. Here's my code:

```
height = data.length * (articleHeight + margin * 2)

timeScale
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) -> timeFormat.parse(d.date)))

div = selection.selectAll(".article").data(data)

div.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "article")
    .html(divHTML)
    .style("top", "0")

div.transition().duration(2000)
    .style("top", (d) -> d3.round(timeScale(timeFormat.parse(d.date))) + "px")
```

The way I'm calculating the height is bad. I've looked into ticks but that's for generating axis right? I've tried to add a 1 day or 3 day tick and it doesn't change a thing (unsurprisingly).

The CSV just in case:

```
date,title,excerpt
2012-08-13,Most recent article,loremasdjf asdflkasfdlaksjdflasdf kjlasdhflkj asdflkja sdklfjhaskdljhfaskdljhfaskldjhf alksjhdf kaljsd fkljas dfkljash dkfaslkdfj
2012-08-4,Second Most recent article,loremasdjf asdflkasfdlaksjdflasdf kjlasdhflkj asdflkja sdklfjhaskdljhfaskdljhfaskldjhf alksjhdf kaljsd fkljas dfkljash dkfaslkdfj
2012-07-15,"July article, bro",loremasdjf asdflkasfdlaksjdflasdf kjlasdhflkj asdflkja sdklfjhaskdljhfaskdljhfaskldjhf alksjhdf kaljsd fkljas dfkljash dkfaslkdfj
2012-01-16,First article of 2012,loremasdjf asdflkasfdlaksjdflasdf kjlasdhflkj asdflkja sdklfjhaskdljhfaskdljhfaskldjhf alksjhdf kaljsd fkljas dfkljash dkfaslkdfj
```

EDIT: There can be more than one article per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix but it's not ideal, I'm still putting it here in case someone finds it useful. Instead of just using the value from the scale, I add a length of the article (a little less actually… told you it wasn't ideal) times the number of articles already displayed. Far from elegant but it works for now, articles never overlap:

```
div.transition().duration(2000)
    .style("top", (d, i) ->
        d3.round(timeScale(timeFormat.parse(d.date))) + i * articleHeight + "px")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed with the height calculation. What you are calculating is the needed height for N articles, where N is the number of articles in your data. However, when you create the scale, you calculate the range from the earliest date to the the latest. So if your first data item is from 01-01-2012 and your last from 31-01-2012, the range will be 30 (or 31 too lazy to check).

So what you basically should do is reuse the d3.extent calculation in the timescale to calculate the height.

**Update**: Okay, so let me elaborate a bit on this. What you want is non-overlapping articles. Therefore you specify a minimal article height. I assume you are using d3.time.scale for timeScale (which is the correct thing to do). For this scale you (also correctly) set the domain as follows:

```
   .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) -> timeFormat.parse(d.date)))
```

The d3.extent function gives you the min and max values, in the case the earliest and the latest date. Now, to calculate the required height, you'll need to take account for the maximum number of articles that might be visible, which is (assuming max one article per day) the number of days between the first and the last date as calculated by d3.extent. To do this you have to calculate the number of days between min and max.

Is set up a jsfiddle which demonstrates this calculation here: http://jsfiddle.net/EA5rP/14/

Comment: Use extent for the range? Which value should I use?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can calculate the required height, given a font height, and assuming max one article per day.

Comment: Thanks but sadly there can be more than one article per day… I should probably have made this clearer, I'm updating my question.

Comment: In that case your use of timeScale is not correct. Given that in your example CSV data there is no time included, two articles with the same data will be mapped to the same vertical position. Still you could do something similar as I did (given that you include time) but you realize that making the range not days but hours or minutes explodes the required vertical space. You probably should rethink if this approach is a useful representation of the data.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I'll stick to my solution for the meantime. I'll continue to do further testing but for now it's working quite well.